# Qt Model/View programming with complicated data structures

Tags: qt, design-patterns, model-view

I am not a professional application developer so am probably not as familiar with the model/view design pattern as I should be. Nonetheless, I am trying to use it in a hobby app and failing miserably. The primary problem I am having is that the data I am trying to display and modify is not easily represented with an extension of `QAbstractItemModel`.

The data I am trying to encapsulate is essentially a growable/shrinkable, mutable list of integers. Should I abandon the model/view pattern for data like this? It seems more appropriate when the "dimensions" of the data are fixed. If not, is there an example of an implementation that I could take a gander at, or a good book that I should pick up?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qabstractlistmodel.html).  It sounds like a more relevant model than the basic `QAbstractItemModel`.

There is also a rather different view of that model in the example: [Puzzle](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/itemviews-puzzle.html)

If you need a higher level look at Model/View, check out [this](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/model-view-programming.html).

Comment: The puzzle example is interesting, but a little odd. Do you happen to understand why the author didn't use the model view pattern for the puzzle widget?

Comment: So I ended up not going with the modelview/pattern. I will do as the author of puzzle did and only implement a view class if I want to make use of the existing QT model classes.

My original plan had been to create a custom model as well. No custom model means no custom view, at least for now.

Comment: Right, only do what is needed.  Don't try to make your model work with a Qt view if it doesn't.  I believe the puzzle example doesn't use Model/View since the QAbstractItemView class really doesn't fit the design.

Answer (score 0):

`QAbstractItemModel` is just one, admittedly very limited way of implementing the Model/View design pattern. If you see that your situation doesn't fit it neatly don't bother working too hard to force it.

A better approach for you would probably be to just pull your own Model class with your own View classes and abandon `QAbstractItemModel`. There is more to this design pattern than the weird flavor implemented in QT and that flavour only works well for very particular applications.

I suggest you read [about it some more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller) and design your own Model-View setup. Your class design is very likely to be cleaner and better understood if you pull your own.

Comment: I think you have to implement QAbstractItemModel if you want to use your model in standard views (tree, table, etc)

Comment: I've considered this, but the real skill I'm exercising with this project is working within a framework (which I do rarely in my "real" job).

Comment: Deriving from and implementing QAbstractItemModel (or one of its derived classes) is how you work within (Qt's) framework :).